# Ошибка в коде на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Взял пример из книги на python 2(мб там все норм), в python 3 выводит ошибку, помогите найти:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]



  def binary_search(lists, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(lists) - 1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high)/2
        guess = lists[mid]
        guess = guess
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1
        if guess < item:
            low = mid + 1
        return None

print (binary_search(my_list, 2))
```

Ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "lesson.py", line 18, in
>   
>       print (binary_search(my_list, 2))   File "lesson.py", line 9, in binary_search
>       guess = lists[mid] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В Python 2 эта строка `mid = (low + high) / 2` вернёт вам целое число, а в Python 3 - вещественное. Очевидно, число вроде `2.5` не может служить для индексации списка, о чём и написано в ошибке. Исправить можно заменой оператора деления на оператор целочисленного деления - `mid = (low + high) // 2`.